# If statement is returning both true and false statment in javascript

Tags: javascript

The function is accepting (val) as an argument and if the (val  == 5) it should execute if statement and return *Equal*, otherwise not equal. But if val is equal to 5 then also function is returning false *Not Equal*. **Beginner Here**.
**Thanks**

**javascript**

```
 function testNotEqual(val) {
    if (val == 5) { 
      return  "Equal";
    }

    else {
      return "Not Equal";
 
    }

    
    
  }
 
  testNotEqual(5);
  console.log(testNotEqual());
```

[image]

Comment: You are calling `testNotEqual` twice: once with 5 once without.

Comment: Your `testNotEqual()` without argument will always return `Not equal`.

Comment: Put `console.log(val);` as the first line of your function `testNotEqual()` and you will see that it once prints `5` as expected. But as your calling it a second time without any parameter, `val` will be `undefined` (thus `undefined` will be printed to the console) and `undefined` is not equal to `5`.  Also, don't know what you are actually trying to do but keep in mind there are different [equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) operators in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  function testNotEqual(val) {
    if (val == 5) { 
      return  "Equal";
    }

    return "Not Equal";
    
  }
 
  let test = testNotEqual(5);
  console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You invoked this function twice and second time you passed nothing as an argument

```js
function testNotEqual(val) {
    if (val === 5) {
      return "Equal";
    } else {
      return "Not Equal";
    }
  }
 
  
  document.getElementById("te").innerHTML = testNotEqual(5);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #333;
}
```

```html
<p style="color:white" >The Result is: <span id="te"></span>
    </p>
```